# Exercise package : use a non-indented list environment for

Tags: exercises, patching

I use the exercise package for typesetting exercises and questions. I would like to avoid the classical indentation of the questions (due to the using of a list environment, but I'm not able to set the options of this list environment).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setlength{\QuestionIndent}{0cm}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{Exercise}
\Question \blindtext
\end{Exercise}


\end{document}
```

By setting `\QuestionIndent`, I get the following : 
[image]

Is it possible to put the number in the text as below ?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no global parameter to handle it, but one can patch the code.  Note that `\item` shifts the label by `\itemindent-\labelwidth-\labelsep` so one can set `\itemindent` to compensate for the other two (of which `\labelsep` at least should not be set to 0pt).

The default `\labelwidth=2em` will place the number slightly indented.  Setting `\labelwidth=0pt` will move the number just to the left of the margin (due to `\hss`).  Using `\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\theQuestion.}` will move the number to the right of the margin.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setlength{\QuestionIndent}{0cm}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@@@Question}{\labelwidth 2em}{\labelwidth 2em \itemindent=\labelwidth \advance\itemindent by \labelsep}{}{}
%\patchcmd{\@@@Question}{\labelwidth 2em}{\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\theQuestion.} \itemindent=\labelwidth \advance\itemindent by \labelsep}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{Exercise}
\Question \blindtext
\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```